# Align vertically with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, navbar

I just read tons of topics about this and I've tried all the possibilities I could find, but I'm still blocked with this problem.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
      <div class="topbg"></div>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="optionFilter">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="linksMenu">
            <a class="active" href="#">1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="linksMenu">
            <a href="#">2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="linksMenu">
            <a href="#" >3</a>
          </li>
          <li class="linksMenu">
            <a href="#">4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-left"></button></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-right"></button></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav><!-- /navbar -->
```

So I've two ULs in my DIV `.navbar-collapse`, but I can't fix the vertical alignment. 
My DIV have a non fixed height and is set automatically with the content, but when I try to set `height : 100%` to my ULs, none change.